# Wordpress Mobile Menu Not Clickable

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, z-index

I have a customer site here: [Gainfield](https://gainfieldgolf.com/)

The mobile menu has stopped working. When I click on the menu, none of the sub items appear. I have added `z-index:1000;` to the `header.header-mobile .header-left #open-left` class with no luck. What am I missing?

Comment: check your console. You got jQuery issues. Doesn't seems css issue

Comment: Thank you @JassPreet